# Angular jasmine: Property does not have access type get

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am aware of similar questions already asked, but absolutely nothing has solved my issue thus far. Perhaps I am missing something.

I have this service that has a getter I want to mock

```
export class UserService {
    private activeUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserModel>;
  
    constructor() {
      this.activeUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(UserHelper.getCurrentUser());
    }
  
    public get activeUserValue(): UserModel {
      return this.activeUserSubject.value;
    }
}
```

All the other answers suggest using SpyOnProperty but it just doesnt work for me. In my spec I attempt to create and mock it but I get the error Property activeUserValue does not have access type get.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    ///other
    let authenticationService: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
    userService = jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>(['activeUserValue']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            ///
        ],
        declarations: [
            ///
        ],
        providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: userService }
        ]
    })
        .compileComponents();
    });

    fit('should create', () => {
        const spy = spyOnProperty(userService, 'activeUserValue', 'get').and.returnValue(of(getMockUser()));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(spy).toBe(getMockUser());
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you do `spyOnProperty(userService,` , you're saying that this `getter` exists on the `spyObject` you created which it doesn't. Once you have mocked `UserService`, its implementation (of whether it uses a getter or what not) is out of the window and we should use the mock.

I would do the following (follow the comments with !!):

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    ///other
    let authenticationService: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
    userService = jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>(['activeUserValue']);
    // !! attach activeUserValue to the spyObject
    userService.activeUserValue = of(getMockUser());
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            ///
        ],
        declarations: [
            ///
        ],
        providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: userService }
        ]
    })
        .compileComponents();
    });

    fit('should create', () => {
        // !! remove this line
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(spy).toBe(getMockUser());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Understand mocking better now